# NSNumberFormatter numberFromString issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I need to take a string from UITextfield and format it into the following:

```
4.99999 -> 4.999
4.12    -> 4.12
.89     -> 0.89

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:3];
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"##0.###"];

DLog(@"formatted number %@",[numberFormatter numberFromString:string]);
```

The problem is that when I type 0.999978 into the textfield and the formatted number is 0.999978 (which isn't correct) it should be 0.999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
NSNumber  *aNum = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[string doubleValue]];
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"##0.###"];
[numberFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor];

DLog(@"formatted string %@",[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:aNum]);
```